# Efficient way to organize used and unused elements in a large concurrent array

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, memory-management, concurrency

I have about 18 million elements in an array that are initialized and ready to be used by a simple manager called `ElementManager` (this number will later climb to a little more than a billion in later iterations of the program). A class, `A`, which must use the elements communicates with `ElementManager` that returns the next available element for consumption. That element is now in use and cannot be reused until recycled, which may happen often. Class `A` is concurrent, that is, it can ask `ElementManager` for an available element in several threads. The elements in this case is an object that stores three vertices to make a triangle.

Currently, the `ElementManager` is using Intel TBB concurrent_bounded_queue called `mAllAvailableElements`. There is also another container (a TBB concurrent_vector) that contains all elements, regardless of whether they are available for use or not, called `mAllElements`. Class `A` asks for the next available element, the manager tries to pop the next available element from the queue. The popped element is now in use.

Now when class `A` has done what it has to do, control is handed to class `B` which now has to iterate through all elements that are `in use` and create meshes *(to take advantage of concurrency, the array is split into several smaller arrays to create submeshes which scales with the number of available threads - the reason for this is that creating a mesh must be done serially)*. For this I am currently iterating over the container `mAllElements` (this is also concurrent) and grabbing any element that is *in use*. The elements, as mentioned above, contain polygonal information to create meshes. Iteration in this case takes a long time as it has to check each element and query whether it is *in use* or not, because if it is not *in use* then it should not be part of a mesh.

Now imagine if only 1 million out of the possible 18 million elements were *in use* (but more than 5-6 million were recycled). Worse yet, due to constant updates to only part of the mesh (which happens concurrently) means the *in use* elements are fragmented throughout the `mAllElements` container.

I thought about this for quite some time now and one flawed solution that I came up with was to create another queue of elements named `mElementsInUse`, which is also a `concurrent_queue`. I can push any element that is now *in use*. Problem with this approach is that since it is a queue, any element in that queue can be recycled at any time (an update in a part of the mesh) and declared *not in use* and since I can only pop the front element, this approach fails. The only other approach I can think of is to defragment the concurrent_vector `mAllElements` every once in a while when no operations are taking place.

I think my approach to this problem is wrong and thus my post here. I hope I explained the problem in enough detail. It seems like a common memory management problem, but I cannot come up with any search terms to search for it.

Comment: Concurrent database for a real-time graphics application? Could you point me to a link?

Comment: Seems like a queue is not the correct container. Seems like what you need is a concurrent linked list to store pointers to your in use elements. Then when a element is taken out of use, it can be removed from the list in contstant time.

Comment: That seems like the only option that I have left. I could not find any implementations of concurrent linked lists however. If you do, please let me know as I would like to avoid making one from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a bit vector to indicate which of your elements are in use? It's easy to partition it for parallel processing when building your full mesh, and you can use atomic operations on words in the vector and thus avoid locks.

Comment: Need to iterate the whole thing though, that's alot of bits.

Comment: I see this being used as an auxiliary structure for status, not for iteration. Recycling means putting an object back onto the `mElementsInUse` queue and setting the bit (assume 1 = available). Now the check for "is this item really in use" is O(1) (just check the bitmap).

Comment: Recycling will put the element in a `mAvailableElements` queue, not `mElementsInUse`. Let's say the 10th element in `mElementsInUse` has to be recycled, I cannot recycle it because it is not at the front of the queue. Thomas's suggestion for a linked list is what I think I will end up using.

Comment: Also, I have thought about using `tbb::atomic<bool>` to indicate the element is in use (so each triangle object also has `tbb::atomic<bool> mInUse`), but the problem remains. I will have to iterate through all elements in order to find out which ones are in use and which ones are not. Every time the manager needs to return an available element, it has to start from the beginning of the container to avoid missing any elements that are no longer in use. In this case, that is 18 million elements (and climbing)

Comment: That would be doing it wrong. You can add the element to a queue, as you planned to do, and then as you pop off items, check the bitmap.